# How to setup ansible passwordless login, if pbrun is being used and rootlogin is disabled

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys, powerbroker

I am new to ansible, We are using pbrun (powerbroker) instead of sudo, and root login is disabled on all servers.
How can I setup passwordless login via ansible master to all slave servers?

My consideration:
We can create ansible user > it should automatically switch to root via pbrun.

How can this be setup?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an user and give it full privileges via pbrun.

In Ansible set:

```
webserver ansible_user=manager ansible_become=true ansible_become_method=pbrun
```

in the inventory. The `become_method`directive can be set from play to task level. Consult the [documentation on become](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) for further instructions.